# Excel - Using 2 seperate values on sheet 1 to reference a cell on sheet 2

Tags: excel, formula

So I have a question. I am looking to have excel auto-populate a cell based off of referencing the data in 2 cells that are on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Sheet 2 contains the dollar figure that I want to display.

On both sheets I have the same training course name and same training location. I have a spot on Sheet 1 to display the cost of the course, but would like it to auto-populate that cell with the information on sheet 2. Sheet 2 has the exact same items; Training Course Name, Training Location but also has the cost of each course listed.

I am using this to track training costs on a per job basis.

[image: Sheet 1]
[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: Your location names aren't exact matches?   This should get you there: https://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a `VLOOKUP` and a `MATCH` function to do it.

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,Sheet2!A2:D15,MATCH(J2,Sheet2!A1:D1))
```

The `MATCH` function returns the index of the column that matches your training facility.  Then the `VLOOKUP` function returns the price.

Edit:  Formula with parameters to look for exact matches.

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,Sheet2!A2:D15,MATCH(J2,Sheet2!A1:D1,0),0)
```

Comment: I tried it using this formula
=VLOOKUP(H13,'Price Index'!A3:L12,MATCH(J13,'Price Index'!A1:L1))
I get an error. My Sheet 2 is Named Price Index.

I edited my names for Locations and Courses Titles to be identical... but I am using them from a drop down box. Could that be the issue?

Comment: The drop downs shouldn't be an issue, but if you have carriage returns in your training facilities, or headers, that will cause an issue.  You could also try to look for exact matches.  To do that, you'd add the option parameter as 0 for both formulas.